# create a vector from a given data frame row wise

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

in R I need to create a vector from a given data frame row wise. for example:

data frame:

```
A  B
1  4
2  5
3  6

vector = 1 4 2 5 3 6
```

couldn't be so hard i think. Thanks so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
> df <- data.frame(A=1:3,B=4:6)

> as.vector(t(df))
[1] 1 4 2 5 3 6
```

Comment: In general, you can run `as.vector` on any matrix, but not dataframe. The command `t(df)` actually creates a matrix. If you want to create a vector column wise instead, run `as.vector(as.matrix(df))`.